# IOException while moving file from one folder to other

Tags: c#, wpf

I am copying file from remote computer to a temp folder in my computer. Then I check md5 of the downloaded file, and move downloaded file from temp folder to current app directory. Here is my method:

```
if (Hasher.HashFile(tempFile, HashType.MD5) != _md5)
{
    DeleteFile(tempFile);
    return false;
}
else
{
    var updatedFile = currentAppLocation+@"\" + appFileName + ".xml";
    //copy to current directory
    if (File.Exists(updatedFile))
        DeleteFile(updatedFile);

    File.Move(tempFile, updatedFile); // here error!

    //delete xml from server
    if (DeleteFile(file))
    {
        //delete txt with checksum from server
        return DeleteFile(txtFile);
    }                        
    return false;
}
```

I always get IOException:

> The process can not access the file because it is being used by another process.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Where do you get `IOException`. Simply debugging your app will most likely point you to the exact problem...

Comment: @MarkJansen I've wrote in code here error! )

Comment: @w.b I do just coping and moving operations, without changing content

Comment: Does the error occur on tempFile, or updatedFile?

Comment: @MarkJansen hm. not sure what do you mena.. I get error while trying to move file from temp location. tempFile exists.

Comment: What has this got do with WPF?   Why have you not rewritten the code to be a small/simple as possible while still showing the problem.  E.g. is async needed to repeat issue?

Comment: Does the file move/copy when the location is local? So remove the remote computer out of the equation first

Comment: `Hasher.HashFile` most likely does not close the file when the hash has been computed.

Comment: @IanRingrose It is part of the wpf app, so ... But may be you are right. And this code is a little simplified. There are some async operations

Comment: @MartinLiversage Thanks Man! Post it like an answer! So stupid mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is copying the file from a network share to a temporary file location. Then the MD5 hash is computed using `Hasher.HashFile` and after that the temporary file is moved using `File.Move`.

But as you have discovered the file cannot be moved because it is already open so the most likely explanation is that `Hasher.HashFile` does not close the file after computing the hash.